# How to center 3 divs with bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

I  have a dilemma here.

I need to center 3 divs using bootstrap.
The problem is the middle divs have to be col-1.
If a do like this:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-auto"> div a</div>
 <div class="col-1">div b</div>
 <div class="col-auto"> div c</div>
</div>
```

I get what I need, in one row but I need to align multiple rows and all have different contents.
I need this to be aligned based on the middle div.
Any ideas?

Solutions using Bootstrap framework, raw CSS, or Sass are welcomne.
[image]

PS: when the company put a backend dev doing front end!
** Thank you **

Comment: are you able to draw a picture of what you want no matter how bad and include it?

Comment: Try [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what version of Bootstrap you're using. If you're using v4 and up you can use the class `justify-content-center` on your `.row` element. For example...

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container my-5">

  <div class="row justify-content-center bg-light py-3">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <div class="bg-secondary p-3 rounded text-nowrap">div a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="bg-primary p-3 rounded text-nowrap">div b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <div class="bg-secondary p-3 rounded text-nowrap">div c</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

More about grid alignment can be found in the docs here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#alignment

---

**EDIT**

Because OP has said the solution above is:

> great for one row. But not for multiple

For multiple rows, you simply repeat the entire `.row` structure... I've put an example together here: https://jsfiddle.net/thelevicole/9axysvun/

I've also created a version that is fully responsive: https://jsfiddle.net/thelevicole/9axysvun/1/ see screenshots below...

Larger devices:

[image: Larger devices]

Smaller devices:

[image: Smaller devices]

Comment: Well no, I need the center div to be col-1 (must), I have tried it but I need multiple rows. that aligns i single row

Comment: @albertosetim the column widths in my answer were examples, I've updated to match those in your question. Does that help?

Comment: I put a pic maybe it is easier to visualize what I need, in the pic is your solution, it's great for one row. But not for multiple.

Comment: @albertosetim Thanks for adding a pic, definitely helpful! Please see my edit above, I've included an example of how to handle multiple rows. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `justify-content-center` to center.

Do not use `col-auto` it won't be responsive. so better to use just `col` or `col-4`..`col-md-4` .it makes responsive automatically

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
 <div class="col-auto">div a</div>
 <div class="col-1">div b</div>
 <div class="col-auto"> div c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I put a pic maybe it is easier to visualize what I need, in the pic is your solution, it's great for one row. But not for multiple

Comment: This works fine for medium and above screens but make it responsive for smaller ones [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-pascal-x618g?file=/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<div class="row col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="col-md-3 box"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 box"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 box"></div>
</div>
```

PS: if this works, then upvote it because I am also a backend guy :p

Comment: Thank you but I have tried that one. It was my first.

Comment: Check the pic I put, maybe helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I am going with for now thank you all.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-md-5 box"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1 box"></div>
  <div class="col-md-5 box"></div>
</div>
```

One col-1 is missing but justify-content-center helps to divide the space between.
Responsive is the next problem doe.